# Does anyone know of a similar site for hardware project collaboration?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, collaboration, project

It seems to me that there are a lot of people out there with great ideas, and unused brain power, who would like to help in the development of Open source Hardware/Software projects.

What's needed is a simple platform (similar to Stack Overflow) where these projects that are in the development stage can be aired in open. Some sort of project administration is needed where tasks can be prioritized and questions and answers to problems posed and where answers can then be provided by users.

People with many different knowledgeable backgrounds all contributing to the development of hardware/software projects I am sure would help improve and speed up development considerably.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a site proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/ and if enough people share your vision, one will be created.  Read through the FAQ there to understand how it works and how best to promote it.